# VB6 backgroud process, how to detect a barcode scanning on another application

Tags: vb6

I am building a background vb program that detect barcode scanning on another application. If a certain string is detected I would want to add another string to the running application by using keySend command in VB. I can read string from keypress or keydown but not barcode scanner.

Comment: Why are you using VB6? What operating systems are you targeting.

Answer (score 1):

Place a Timer control on the form called `Timer1`

```
Private Declare Function GetAsyncKeyState Lib "User32" (ByVal vKey As KeyCodeConstants) As Long

Private barcode As String

Private Sub Timer1_Timer()
    Dim keyResult As Integer
    Dim chrKey As String
    Dim i As Integer
    For i = 2 To 90
        keyResult = 0
        keyResult = GetAsyncKeystate(i)
        If keyResult = -32767 Then
            chrKey = Chr(i)
            barcode = barcode & chrKey
            Exit For
        End If
    Next i
End Sub
```

This is a keylogger. It will log all keys pressed. Set the Timer interval to the speed of the scanner so you don't get duplicate keystrokes.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand you correctly, your issue is how to detect when an app scans a code?

How is the scan performed, manual keyboard entry or using a barcode scanner device?

If its using a device, then it all depends on the device. I've worked with just a few devices, and what they did is whenever you scan something, it copies data from the barcode into clipboard (as if you pressed CTRL+C to copy a line of text).

So all you have to do is monitor the clipboard for a specific string and then do whatever you needed to do.

Comment: Never seen a barcode scanner use the clipboard. Always seen then act like a keyboard and just send the keystrokes. What scanner did you use?

Comment: Oh I don't remember, its been over 5 years maybe. It was a small simple  handheld device. It was pretty reliable and easy to use and no installation or software was needed. You just plug the scanner into USB and use it. Every time you scan a code it would copy the code into clipboard and simulate CTRL+V - meaning if your cursor was in a text box, or notepad or anything in windows environment you can paste into, it would paste the code from clipboard there.

Comment: Using the clipboard behind the scenes is almost always a bad idea. You interfere with the end-user's clipboard operations. I highly doubt that a real company would sell something that did this. All barcode scanners I have used just send the characters directly to the cursor when scanned similar to a keyboard. It's possible there was a setting you had selected, but I would not assume it is the norm, nor code for this functionality - it is just bad.

Comment: @Dan Verdolino You are probably be right about the clipboard part, its possible that that was part of a setting or just customized behaviour specific to that application.